# Using OpenGL to draw directly to a .NET Bitmap

Tags: .net, opengl, c++-cli

I'd like to use OpenGL to draw directly to a .NET System::Drawing::Bitmap (C++/CLI). It seems like it should work like this:

```
char buf[48];
ZeroMemory( &buf, sizeof(buf));
System::Drawing::Bitmap bmp(
    4,
    4,
    12,
    Imaging::PixelFormat::Format24bppRgb,
    (System::IntPtr)buf);
Graphics^ g = Graphics::FromImage(%bmp);
HDC local_hdc = (HDC)((void*)g->GetHdc());
HGLRC local_hrc = wglCreateContext( local_hdc );
if(!wglMakeCurrent( local_hdc, local_hrc ))
    ShowError();

//Draw something with OpenGL ...

g->ReleaseHdc((IntPtr)((void*)local_hdc));

//Do something with the bitmap ...
```

But wglMakeCurrent fails with "The pixel format is invalid".

"Of course!" I think. "I just need to set the pixel format of the bitmap in such a way that OpenGL can render to it!"

Sadly, if I use the above Bitmap constructor, I'm limited to an enum of canned pixelformats, rather than a struct holding a bunch of attributes that I can OR together. And I don't think it's possible to set the pixel format after the fact.

Anyway, this way of doing things would be prettier than using a bunch of Win32 calls to make a Device-Independent Bitmap, but the canned pixel formats seem to omit any sort of GL-enabled anything, and I just fail. Can you succeed?

Answer (score 3):

You probably don't want to draw directly into your buffer anyway, you'd lose all hardware acceleration which is the advantage of OpenGL to begin with.  Instead:

- Set up an OpenGL context as usual, using video RAM.
- Draw into it, fully accelerated.
- Create a Bitmap.
- Call Bitmap::LockBits to get the pointer to the raw pixel memory.
- Use glCopyImage to read the results from video RAM into the Bitmap.

The PixelFormat passed to LockBits and glCopyImage in the last two steps need to match of course.

Comment: Ah, but I do want to draw directly into my bitmap buffer! That's because I'm trying to get a bitmap ready to send to a printer. This means I only have to draw once, so speed isn't a big issue, and if I can draw directly to the buffer I avoid duplicating a really big bitmap in memory.

Comment: The method I suggested won't use any additional system RAM, only video RAM.  How big is this bitmap?  I guess if you're trying to render an 8.5"x11" at 1200 dpi (that's 400MB) it might not fit in video RAM but... I don't know if OpenGL would support a rendering surface that large anyway.

Why are you wanting OpenGL for this?  3-D rendering?  Lots of textured quads?  Reuse of existing render routines already needed for screen display?

Comment: Hm, sorry to let this hang for, like, ever. The image is likely to be that large, and larger for larger paper sizes. I want to use OpenGL for this because I am using OpenGL for rendering the view on screen, and the printout needs to match the screen view as exactly as possible ... just at a higher resolution. So basically, what I want to do is when the user says "print", I want to draw once, directly into the buffer of a .NET bitmap (in my .NET client at least), which can then be easily sent to the printer.