# Draw OpenGL to an offscreen bitmap

Tags: c++, windows, opengl, bitmap

I've inherited a project which renders a 3D scene directly to the window using OpenGL. The code works fine, but we're now drawing an icon onto the 3D view to "Exit 3D view mode". This also works fine, but results in a lot of flickering as the view is rapidly rotated.

I'd like to be able to draw to an off-screen bitmap (ie. without a HWND), then draw my icon to the bitmap, then finally `StretchBlt` the bitmap to the window using double-buffering. We do this in other contexts (such as zooming into an image which does not need OpenGL) and it works great. My problem is that I am an OpenGL novice and all attempts at starting with the DC of the off-screen bitmap and creating a HWND from this DC fail, usually because of selecting a pixel format for the DC.

There are a few questions asking similar things here on StackOverflow ([eg. this question without an accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2284620/using-opengl-to-draw-directly-to-a-net-bitmap). Is this possible ? If so is there a relatively straightforward tutorial describing the procedure? If the process is extremely complex requiring detailed OpenGL knowledge, then I may just have to leave it and live with the flickering because it is a rarely used mode in our software.

Answer (score 0):

Just draw the Icon using OpenGL using a textured quad.

All this draw to a bitmap copy to DC StretchBlt involves several roundtrips from and to graphics memory (wastes bandwidth) and StretchBlt will likely not be GPU accelerated. All in all what you want to do is inefficient and may even reduce quality.

I presume you have the icon stored in your executable as a resource. The most simple way to go about it is to create a memory DC (CreateCompatibleDC) with a DIBSECTION (CreateDIBSection), draw the icon to that and load the DIBSECTION data into a OpenGL texture. Then to draw the icon use `glViewport` to select the destination rectangle in window coordinates, use an identity transform to draw a rectangle covering the whole viewport (position values (-1,1)→(1,1), texture coordinate values (0,0)→(1,1) gives you the right outcome).

Important side fix: In case your program does silly things like setting viewport and the fixed function pipeline GL_PROJECTION matrix in a window resize handler you should clean up that anti pattern and move this to where it belongs: In the drawing code.